# Transparent animated graphics in Kivy

Tags: kivy

I am new to Kivy and want to create a widge graphic image of a tank with a transparent cutout that "fills" with another graphic image of the product. How do I stack 2 graphic images, one with a transparent layer, on top of one another to get this effect? I have created this with a circle/rectangle and fill color, but I want both a custom foreground image and a custom fill image.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack `Image` widgets by simply placing them at the same position. For example, in `kv` you can do:

```
FloatLayout:
    Image:
        source: 'fill.png'
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        allow_stretch: True
    Image:
        source: 'tank.png'
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        allow_stretch: True
```

This will show the `tank.png` with the `fill.png` showing through any transparent areas of `tank.png`.

Comment: I forgot about the floatlayout. Yes- that is the key. Thanks